# Curve fitting for non-linear data

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, non-linear-regression

I am trying to fit some data using `lsqcurvefit` in MATLAB but I am fairly new to this area.

```
xdata1 = [0 60 660 1250];
ydata1 = [0 18 23 31];
```

In the image below, the red line is the fit I want to achieve.

[image: red is desired fit]

How can I achieve this fit?

Comment: If you fit the first two points to a straight line, and then fit the last three points to a different straight line (so that the x=60 point is in both fits) you could switch between them at the crossing point of x =60. This simple method will likely yield a small, sudden change when crossing from one model to the other at x=60.

Answer (score 0):

How about polyfit() ?

Code here:

```
close all % be careful with following two lines
clear all

x = [0 60 660 1250];
y = [0 18 23 31]; 

p = polyfit(x,y,3);

xx = linspace(x(1), x(end), 100);
yy = polyval(p,xx);

plot(x,y,'o'); hold on; plot(xx,yy)
```

[image]

Comment: As the two images show very different function plots, how does this answer the question that was asked?

Comment: Hi Marc, thank you for your answer! However I used polyfit for a first draft and the fit is not good enough.  I would need a surrogate function , or two linear function which can converted to one.